# clock() in opencl

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu

I know that there is function clock() in CUDA where you can put in kernel code and query the GPU time. But I wonder if such a thing exists in OpenCL? Is there any way to query the GPU time in OpenCL? (I'm using NVIDIA's tool kit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NVIDIA OpenCL SDK has an example [Using Inline PTX with OpenCL](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/sdk/website/OpenCL/html/samples.html). The clock register is accessible through inline PTX as the special register %clock. %clock is described in [PTX: Parallel Thread Execution ISA](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/ptx_isa_2.3.pdf) manual. You should be able to replace the %%laneid with %%clock.

I have never tested this with OpenCL but use it in CUDA.

Please be warned that the compiler may reorder or remove the register read.

Comment: Yes, this is the most possible solution so far I would say. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is no OpenCL way to query clock cycles directly. However, OpenCL does have a profiling mechanism that exposes incremental counters on compute devices. By comparing the differences between ordered events, elapsed times can be measured. See clGetEventProfilingInfo.

Comment: I think that would give the execution time of the whole kernel. But I want to query timing for a specific number of work-items or work-groups. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not directly, but you could enqueue a kernel with a specific number of work items or work groups and profile it.

Comment: Yeah I got what you meant. But things are a little bit more complicated. The timing of a work-item is different depending on how many work-items are there in total. For example if there are resources contention then executing only one work-group will be faster than having multiple work-groups together. So I guess profiling (timing) individual work-items, or even work-groups is not yet implemented in OpenCL.

Answer (score 4):

Just for others coming her for help: Short introduction to profiling kernel runtime with OpenCL

Enable profiling mode:

```
cmdQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, *devices, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &err);
```

Profiling kernel:

```
cl_event prof_event; 
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQueue, kernel, 1 , 0, globalWorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, &prof_event);
```

Read profiling data in:

```
cl_ulong ev_start_time=(cl_ulong)0;     
cl_ulong ev_end_time=(cl_ulong)0;   

clFinish(cmdQueue);
err = clWaitForEvents(1, &prof_event);
err |= clGetEventProfilingInfo(prof_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(cl_ulong), &ev_start_time, NULL);
err |= clGetEventProfilingInfo(prof_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(cl_ulong), &ev_end_time, NULL);
```

Calculate kernel execution time:

```
float run_time_gpu = (float)(ev_end_time - ev_start_time)/1000; // in usec
```

Profiling of individual work-items / work-goups is NOT possible yet. 
You can set globalWorkSize = localWorkSize for profiling. Then you have only one workgroup.

Btw: Profiling of a single work-item (some work-items) isn't very helpful. With only some work-items you won't be able to hide memory latencies and the overhead leading to not meaningful measurements.

Comment: NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition performs the aforementioned tasks transparent to your application and displays the information in a tabular view as well as on a timeline. The tool works on most OpenCL platforms as it works at the ICD layer. OpenCL does not support a mechanism to synchronize the CPU and GPU timers so the timeline may have synchronization problems (skew, drift) on non-NVIDIA platforms. Other OpenCL vendors have similar tools.

Answer (score 4):

Try this (Only work with NVidia OpenCL of course) :

```
uint clock_time()
{
    uint clock_time;
    asm("mov.u32 %0, %%clock;" : "=r"(clock_time));
    return clock_time;
}
```

Comment: update: since ptx version 2.0 there is a %clock64 register too

Answer (score 2):

On NVIDIA you can use the following:

```c
typedef unsigned long uint64_t; // if you haven't done so earlier
inline uint64_t n_nv_Clock()
{
    uint64_t n_clock;
    asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%clock64;" : "=l" (n_clock)); // make sure the compiler will not reorder this
    return n_clock;
}
```

The `volatile` keyword tells the optimizer that you really mean it and don't want it moved / optimized away. This is a standard way of doing so both in [PTX](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html#incorrect-optimization) and e.g. in [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile).

Note that this returns *clocks*, not nanoseconds. You need to query for device clock frequency (using `clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY, sizeof(freq), &freq, 0))`). Also note that on older devices there are two frequencies (or three if you count the memory frequency which is irrelevant in this case): the device clock and the shader clock. What you want is the shader clock.

With the 64-bit version of the register you don't need to worry about overflowing as it generally takes hundreds of years. On the other hand, the 32-bit version can overflow quite often (you can still recover the result - unless it overflows twice).

Answer (score 0):

Now, 10 years later after the question was posted I did some tests on NVidia. I tried running the answers given by user 'Spectral' and 'the swine'. Answer given by 'Spectral' does not work. I always got same invalid values returned by clock_time function.

```
uint clock_time()
{
    uint clock_time;
    asm("mov.u32 %0, %%clock;" : "=r"(clock_time)); // this is wrong
    return clock_time;
}
```

After subtracting start and end time I got zero.

So had a look at the PTX assembly which in PyOpenCL you can get this way:

```
kernel_string = """
your OpenCL code
"""

prg = cl.Program(ctx, kernel_string).build()

print(prg.binaries[0].decode())
```

It turned out that the clock command was optimized away! So there was no '%clock' instruction in the printed assembly.

Looking into [Nvidia's PTX documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html#incorrect-optimization) I found the following:

'Normally any memory that is written to will be specified as an out operand, but if there is a hidden side effect on user memory (for example, indirect access of a memory location via an operand), or if you want to stop any memory optimizations around the asm() statement performed during generation of PTX, you can add a "memory" clobbers specification after a 3rd colon, e.g.:'

So the function that actually work is this:

```
uint clock_time()
{
    uint clock_time;
    asm volatile ("mov.u32 %0, %%clock;" : "=r"(clock_time) :: "memory");
    return clock_time;
}
```

The assembly contained lines like:

```
    // inline asm
    mov.u32 %r13, %clock;
    // inline asm
```

The version given by 'the swine' also works.